# Google Groups Java API - Unsubscribe a domain user from an external group

Tags: java, google-api, google-groups-api

We're wanting to unsubscribe a domain user from an external group that they are a member of.  For example :

mike@domain.com is a member of group@externalgroup.com

Is there a way through the API to remove mike@domain.com as a member of group@externalgroup.com .  If we try this via the Google API it throws the following error :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
```

Because we're trying to modify the membership of a group outside the domain.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the Directory Groups API only allows management of groups in your domain.